# Differential Equation of orbit of a planet

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, polar-coordinates, implicit-differentiation

Every where I found the solution of the differential equation orbit ( they make the differential equation in the 1st place )  by letting r=1/u  , using reciprocal coordinates.

I was trying  to do away with this substitution but I couldn't form the equation.

**I was having a problem in whether (r) is a function of theta which in turn is a function of t or is r directly a function of t. Or is theta the function of r and then r is a function of t or theta directly a function of t**. I tried this but produced a mess

I need help in forming the equation without using u , just r and in understanding what is function of what both implicitly and explicitly !

**Edit:**

After searching on the net I found out that without taking the substitution , I had actually formed the correct equation but that equation is non linear ! I got that correct non linear equation. To solve the equation we use the substitution r=1/u which will linearize it. So it's just linearization !

What I want is that please someone check 
This statement

***"whether (r) is a function of theta which in turn is a function of t or is r directly a function of t. Or is theta the function of r and then r is a function of t or theta directly a function of t"***

What is correct in the above statement ? *I am getting confused because if theta is function of r then the differential equation would be different* . **Would it be so that we just replace r and theta in final answer and get the same answer back ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Polar coordinates**

The movement vector $\vec{OP}=\vec r$ in polar coordinates depends of $\theta$ which in turn depends of $t$, so $r=r(\theta(t))$.

But we will see that if $\theta$ is a convenient angle to describe the trajectory curve it is not straightforward to describe how $P$ evolves in time (or equivalently, to have a formula for $\theta(t)$). Instead we will introduce a new *"angle"* $E$ named eccentric anomaly and we will see that there are formulas to relate $E\leftrightarrow\theta$ and also to relate $E\leftrightarrow t$.

Thus giving a way via $E$ intermediate to express both $r$ and $\theta$ as direct functions of time $t$.

---

**Central force movement**

gravity law : $m\vec{\ddot r}=\vec F=-\frac{\mathcal GmM}{r^3}\vec r\quad$ where $m$ is planet mass and $M$ is sun mass.

moment law : $\vec\sigma_O=\vec{OP}\wedge m\vec v=\vec r\wedge m\vec{\dot r}$

When derivating we get $\frac{\partial\vec\sigma_O}{\partial t}=\vec{\dot r}\wedge m\vec{\dot r}+\vec r\wedge m\vec{\ddot r}=0+\vec r\wedge\vec F=\vec 0\quad$ since $F$ is a radial force.

Thus $\vec\sigma_O$ is a constant $\vec C$, we name it the *area constant*.

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid] {\vec C=\vec r\wedge\vec{\dot r}}$

In the frame $(\vec i,\vec j,\vec k)$ defined by $\vec i=\frac{\vec r}{r},\ \vec j=\frac{\partial\vec i}{\partial\theta},\ \vec k=\vec i\wedge\vec j$.

*Note: $\vec i=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)$ so $(\vec i,\vec j,\vec k)$ is a well defined orthonormal frame.*

Let's multiply by $\vec v=\vec{\dot r}$ and calculate the kinetic energy : $m\,\vec{\ddot r}.\vec{\dot r}=-\mathcal GmM\,\frac{\vec r.\vec{\dot r}}{r^3}\ $

integrating this gives $\frac12mv^2=+\mathcal GmM\frac 1r+cst$

We call the arbitrary integration constant $h=\frac{cst}{m}$ and also $\bbox[5px,border:1px solid]{\mu=\mathcal GM}$

$\vec{\dot r}=\frac{\partial(r\vec i)}{\partial t}=\dot r\,\vec i+r\dot\theta\,\vec j\quad$ from this we get $\vec C=r^2\dot\theta\,\vec k\ $ and $\ v^2={\dot r}^2+r^2{\dot\theta}^2$

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid] {\begin{array}{cc} C=r^2\dot\theta\\ \frac12({\dot r}^2+r^2{\dot\theta}^2)-\frac{\mu}{r}=h \end{array}}$

---

**Conic trajectory**

This is where the manipulation is a bit artificial, we express $\dot r=\dot\theta\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ in terms of $\dot\theta=\frac{C}{r^2}$

giving $\frac12(\frac{C^2}{r^4}(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2+\frac{C^2}{r^2})-\frac{\mu}{r}=h,\quad$and we do the change of variable $\frac1r=u+\frac{\mu}{C^2}$.

I do not detail the calculacy but this gives :

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid] {(\frac{du}{d\theta})^2+u^2=\frac{\mu^2e^2}{C^4}}\quad$ where $\ \bbox[5px,border:1px solid]{e=\sqrt{1+\frac{2hC^2}{\mu^2}}}\ $ is called the eccentricity.

This integrates into $u=\frac{\mu e}{C^2}\cos(\theta-\theta_0)$ and we will introduce yet some new notations.

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid] {\begin{array}{c} \nu=\theta-\theta_0 \\ p=\frac{C^2}{\mu} \\ \end{array}}\quad$ giving $\quad\bbox[5px,border:3px solid blue] {r=\frac{p}{1+e\cos \nu}}$

We can remark that :

- $e=0\quad$ this is a circle
- $h<0\Rightarrow 0<e<1\quad$ this is an ellipse
- $h=0\Rightarrow e=1\quad$ this is a parabola
- $h>0\Rightarrow e>1\quad$ this is an hyperbola

The case which interest us currently is the ellipse. Let's call $2a$ the `length of the major axis`.

We see that $r$ is minimum for $\nu=0$ and $r_{min}=a(1-e)=\frac p{1+e}$

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid] {p=a(1-e^2)}\quad$ remark that we have also $a=\frac{\mu}{-2h}$, we will use it later.

*Note: for Earth $e\simeq0.0167$ and $a\sim1\,UA\simeq149\,598\,000\ km$*

---

**Third law of Kepler**

Let's introduce our new angles.

- $\nu$ is called the `true anomaly`
- $E$ is called the `eccentric anomaly`
- $M=n(t-t0)=2\pi(\frac{t-t0}{T})$ is called the `mean anomaly`, $n$ the frequency and $T$ the period.

With the new angle $E$ we have

$\begin{cases}
x=r\cos\nu=a(\cos E-e) \\
y=r\sin\nu=b\sin E=a\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin E \\
\end{cases}$

The equation of the ellipse becomes $\bbox[5px,border:3px solid blue] {r=a(1-e\cos E)}$

We deduce also without much trouble that $\bbox[5px,border:3px solid green] {\tan(\frac{\nu}{2})=\sqrt\frac{1+e}{1-e}\tan(\frac E2)}$

The tedious part is establishing the `Kepler's equation`. I will not detail everything here, but basically you define $dt=\frac{r}{\sqrt{-2h}}d\tilde E$ an elementary area element.

Then by replacing $r,\dot r,\ddot r$ by the appropriate terms $r,r'=\frac{dr}{d\tilde E},r''=\frac{d^2r}{d\tilde E^2}$ in the equation $r\ddot r+{\dot r}^2=2h+\frac{\mu}{r}$ obtained by eliminating $\dot \theta$ from the movement equation.

You eventually arrive to $\bbox[5px,border:1px solid] {r''+r=a}$ which combined to $\sqrt{-2h}(t-t_0)=\int\limits_0^{\tilde E} r(\tilde E)d\tilde E$ proves to be compatible with the $E=\tilde E$ and $r(E)$.

The latter integral relation gives you $\sqrt{-2h}(t-t_0)=a(E-e\sin E)$

We define $\bbox[5px,border:3px solid green] {M=2\pi(\frac{t-t_0}{T})=E-e\sin E}$ and gain $Ma=\frac{2\pi a}{T}=\sqrt{-2h}=\sqrt\frac{\mu}{a}$

which is the famous $\bbox[5px,border:1px solid] {\frac{T^2}{a^3}=\frac{4\pi^2}{\mu}}\ $.

---

As promised we have now the two blue movement trajectories $r(\theta),r(E)$ expressed in two different frames, and the angles $\theta,E$ are linked to the time $t$ thanks to the green equations.

Comment: Thanks for this great precise answer. So we r(theta(t)) is the correct one . We change r=1/u to save the non linearity  , else we  get a non linear equation . So we want the solution in r(theta) since theta(t) we can not always know theta(t) . Is that right ?

Comment: @Shashaank Yes, u is really no more than a temporary convenience to ease the calculation. And yes also for theta(t), since E-e sin(E)=M is a transcendent equation we cannot express E=f(t) and furthermore theta(t).

Comment: By the way if we use r not u , is there any method to solve non linear Equations ?

Comment: @Shashaank But even with u, this is non-linear...

Comment: Was back here. Can you help in this - In the above equation for the planet in an orbit - r changes with the angle  . So r is a function of angle. Angle changes with t . So r=r(theta(t)). But it can be the other way too - If you visualize  , then angle changes with r which itself changes with t. Or t changes with r which changes which changes with angle....So on. So theta=theta(r(t)) or t=t(r(theta)). That's right ? But we use only the 1st one since only that is useful here ,the rest are not

Comment: @Shashaank It is true but in addition to that, the other ways leads to difficulties to get explicit functions. M=E-esinE cannot be expressed E=f(M) with usual functions, also $\nu$ would need arctan of an expression with tan in it, and E would be something in arccos(r), these are not very pleasant to manipulate.

Comment: Ok thanks! So I am right in thinking that way - That both r can be a function of angle which is a function of t. Or angle is a function of r which is a function of t. Or t is a function of r which is a function of angle.... at least they will be a sort of inverse functions of each other.... Or I can take it that way that r is function of both angle & t. Or angle is function of both r & t. Then probably we will have to use partial differentiation.... But that would be even more complicated. That's all right ? At least I am right in thinking what is a function of what?

Comment: Because in other questions in Physics also , we have to sort of know before solving what is a function of what . So I want to know that this thinking is right or not ?

Comment: $\int\limits_0^{\tilde E} r(\tilde E)d\tilde E$ seems wrong: integration limit and the variable we are integrating with respect to should not be the same. Nice post btw.

Comment: @zabop I know, this paragraph establishing Kepler's equation is not well redacted. I redacted this post from old lesson notes I had when I was a student, and this part was fuzzy to say the least, I just filled the holes with the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Without the substitution $r=1/u$ it will indeed be a mess. $ r, \theta $ as time dependents are involved with elliptic integrals/functions.

The equations of motion can be numerically integrated more easily.

Unfortunately the planetary orbit equation in its simplest form ( major axis along x-axis, focus at origin) combines  coordinates from Cartesian and Polar forms

$$ p =r - e\cdot x $$

which when differentiated with respect to arc I found leads to a simple form as its geometric property:

$$ \dfrac{\cos \psi}{\cos \phi} =e. $$

( Angles which conic tangent makes to radius and x-axis respy.)

Comment: So it's not possible without the substitution . Plus whether (r) is a function of theta which in turn is a function of t or is r directly a function of t. Or is theta the function of r and then r is a function of t or theta directly a function of t. Which of the above is right

Comment: Both are right. Classical Newton derivation ( tangential equilibrium gives constant r^2*omega,then  plug it into radial equilibrium differential equation) is simpler.

Comment: Just to check. Your previous comment was regarding r being a function of theta or theta being a function of r.....so on.....Right ? For it you said both are right . Right ? Or you said we can have an equation in r without the substitution

Comment: First time, next  theta as indep. variable. Check Wiki or textbook. Extended comments may get moderated.