# How do I solve an equation of the form $(\ddot{r}-\frac{A}{r^3})=B$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

Can we solve an equation of the form $$(\ddot{r}-\frac{A}{r^3})=B$$ where

- $A$, $B$ are constants subjected to the initials conditions $r=R$,
- and $\dot{r}=v$ at $t=0$?

Overhead dots represent derivatives w.r.t time $t$. This is the equation I arrived at while solving a physics problem, and it remains to solve this equation.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dt}\dot{r}^2=2\dot{r}\ddot{r}$.

Comment: This vaguely seems like a orbits problem - if you're looking for a more satisfying answer you could consider writing the equation in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ only, that is, $dr/d \theta$ as opposed to $dr/dt$ and so on.

Comment: Looks like gravity law indeed with an additional term $B$. Orbit movement needs moment law to help solving this thing. Also generally as suggested by B.Mehta there is no easy solutions expressed as $r(t)$ but instead $r(\theta)$ combined with a transcendent relation between $t$ and $\theta$. If you are interested I wrote a presentation some time ago $\to$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140677/differential-equation-of-orbit-of-a-planet/2141482#2141482

Answer (score 6):

$$\ddot{r}-\frac{A}{r^3}=B$$
$$2\ddot{r}\dot{r}-\frac{2A\dot{r}}{r^3}=2B\dot{r}$$
$$\dot{r}^2+\frac{A}{r^2}=2Br+c_1$$
At $t=0\quad\to\quad v^2+\frac{A}{R^2}=2BR+c_1\quad$ leads to :
$$\dot{r}^2+\frac{A}{r^2}=2Br+v^2+\frac{A}{R^2}-2BR$$
$$\dot{r}=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{A}{r^2}+2Br+v^2+\frac{A}{R^2}-2BR}$$
$$\frac{dr}{\sqrt{-\frac{A}{r^2}+2Br+v^2+\frac{A}{R^2}-2BR}}=dt$$
$$\int\frac{dr}{\sqrt{-\frac{A}{r^2}+2Br+v^2+\frac{A}{R^2}-2BR}}=t+c_2$$ 
At $r(0)=R$ leads to :
$$t(r)=\int_{\rho=R}^{\rho=r}\frac{d\rho}{\sqrt{-\frac{A}{\rho^2}+2B\rho+v^2+\frac{A}{R^2}-2BR}}$$
The closed form $t(r)$ of this elliptic integral is very complicated. Moreover, the inverse function $r(t)$ should be even more nightmarish, of the kind of generalized Jacobi elliptic functions. It is doubtful than a closed form could be derived.